# Xamarin does not delete data from a table

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, android-sqlite

I am developing an app in Xamarin.
I delete the data from the app in SQLite and uninstall it, but when I reinstall it, the data in the tables is still there.

```
public void DeleteCompras()
        {
            _database.DropTableAsync<CompraMetales>().Wait();
            _database.CreateTableAsync<CompraMetales>().Wait();
            _database.DeleteAllAsync<CompraMetales>().Wait();
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: is this user generated data, or data that is either pre-populated or populated at startup?  And you should await async methods, not use Wait()

Comment: But i'm so stupid, thanks, what you are downloading is what the app should download

Comment: You are not stupid, the code that you are using as a sample isn't showing everything that is needed.  Everybody makes the same mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You need disable all debug optimisation, also add that flags into android manifest file:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/iii" android:largeHeap="true" android:allowBackup="false" android:allowClearUserData="true">
```

Also try replace ypur code

```
public async void DeleteCompras()
{
    await _database.DropTableAsync<CompraMetales>();
    await _database.CreateTableAsync<CompraMetales>();
    await _database.DeleteAllAsync<CompraMetales>();
}
```